# How do I add a new language syntax to Monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I added my language and followed the instructions here to build 
https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-languages

```
npm run prepublish
```

This outputs a release folder with dev, esm and min folders inside, but what to do with this output to add it to the Monaco editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to test things out:

```
~$ git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor
~$ cd monaco-editor
~/monaco-editor$ npm install .
~/monaco-editor$ npm run simpleserver
```

Just make sure `monaco-editor` and `monaco-languages` (or any other plugins) are under the same directory.

If you want to create your own release then you can simply edit https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/metadata.js#L68-L70 to point to your `monaco-languages`. I guess you could also update the package.json to install your own version of `monaco-languages`, or simple copy over your `~/monaco-languages/release` folder to `~/monaco-editor/node_modules/monaco-languages/`.

After that just `~/monaco-editor$ npm run release` and you'll get your release folder.