# Failing to add a new monaco-language; not sure what I'm missing

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying to add a new language to monaco-editor by way of updating a local version of monaco-languages, but the new language never appears in the list of languages in sample website.

I've cloned both projects.  I followed the instructions for adding a language at https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-languages

Then I use npm pack to create a tar.gz

I run `npm install monaco-languages-2.6.1-mylang.tgz` in monaco-editor and then

Then I use the instruction https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor to release and run the webserver

I can see that my changes are in node-modules.  I can see that package.json is referencing the correct (new) tar.gz.

If I update monaco-editor/website/index/index.js, those changes are reflected

But `monaco.languages.getLanguages()` continues to return the original list of languages.

I feel like I must be doing something wrong with packaging and running, but can't see what it is.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

- I didn't rename the project, I just changed the version to "2.6.1-mylang".
- I did see this [How do I add a new language syntax to Monaco editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50606676/1033953)
- I renamed monaco-language to mylang-language to make sure I wasn't accidentally getting the original package.  I feel like I must not be registering the language correctly in monaco.contribution.ts because my new language files are included in the node-modules directory..  they're just not appearing when I call monaco.languages from monaco-editor

Comment: Do you want to add the language as a newly supported language for the monaco-editor project as such or rather add a new language just for your own application?

Comment: Just for my own application.